# Scripting htdigest -c /path/to/file/$user $user $password in Bash

Tags: command-line, scripting, password, apache-httpd

I want to be able to script with a password in variable $password.

```
htdigest -c /etc/apache2/pw/$user $user $password
```

At the moment it asks me to manually enter a password; this is not going to be possible since it will be an automated setup by a PHP script. 
Could someone please show me how to script this? Or an equivalent scriptable function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645659/how-do-you-htdigest-400-user-accounts

The easiest method, based on one of the suggestions in the top-voted answer, is probably this:

```
digest="$( printf "%s:%s:%s" "$user" "$realm" "$password" | 
           md5sum | awk '{print $1}' )"

printf "%s:%s:%s\n" "$user" "$realm" "$digest" >> "/etc/apache2/pw/$user"
```

I've used `md5sum` from GNU coreutils and `awk` rather than just `md5` because it's what i have installed on my system and I couldn't be bothered finding out which package contains `/usr/bin/md5` - you could also use `sha512sum` or other hashing program.

e.g. if **user=foo**, **realm=bar**, and **password=baz** then the command above will produce:

```
foo:bar:5bf2a4095f681d1c674655a55af66c5a
```

htdigest doesn't do anything magical or even unusual - it just outputs the user, realm, and password in the right format...as the command above does.

Deleting the digest for a given user:realm instead of just adding one, can easily be done with sed.

```
sed -i -e "/^$user:$realm:/d" "/etc/apache2/pw/$user"
```

And updating/changing the digest for a user:realm can also be done with sed in combination with the method above to generate the digest line.  e.g.

```
digest="$( printf "%s:%s:%s" "$user" "$realm" "$new_password" | 
           md5sum | awk '{print $1}' )"

sed -i -e "/^$user:$realm:/ c$user:$realm:$digest" "/etc/apache2/pw/$user"
```

Comment: awesome :P had some issues when the file didn't already exist, so i create the file before running this :o

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'proc_open' function in PHP
http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

You can run htdigest with your option, then send in the pipes the new password.

You can probably found/create a PHP function which do the htdigest job. It should be easier thant use proc_open...

Comment: it's much more complex than just making a new apache user :p using php is not an option